Awesome WM: Natural scrolling does not work in Firefox
I am using Awesome WM on Debian. Natural scrolling on my touchpad works fine in all applications I have tested (terminals, libreoffice, evince, google-chrome, ...) except for Firefox. When I boot with GNOME instead of Awesome WM, the natural scrolling propagates even into Firefox. Any idea why it does not work in Firefox in Awesome WM and how to fix it?
This is the content of my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

